# migrate Civi data from Drupal to Joomla

Tags: drupal, joomla, migration

I am getting ready to migrate a Drupal 7 site running CiviCRM 5.44 to a Joomla 3.10.4 site running CiviCRM 5.44 for Joomla.

Can someone point me to directions for doing this migration of Civi for Drupal to Civi for Joomla?  I understand the best method is to make an SQL dump of the CiviCRM database tables, and then import that into the Joomla database.

thanks,
JC

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switching-cms/switch-cms/  It does not have Drupal to Joomla but the guides cover the steps that need to be done.

And once you figure it out, it would be great if you write a new guide to improve the documentation!